# which tasks can simple perceptron perform?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, perceptron

I'm trying to teach simple single neuron perceptron to recognize repetitive sequences of `1`.

here is data I use to teach it:

```
learning_signals = [
  [[1, 1, 0, 0], 1],
  [[1, 1, 0, 1], 1],
  [[1, 1, 1, 0], 1],

  [[0, 1, 1, 0], 1],
  [[0, 1, 1, 1], 1],


  [[0, 0, 1, 1], 1],
  [[1, 0, 1, 1], 1],

  [[0, 0, 0, 0], 0],
  [[1, 0, 0, 0], 0],
  [[0, 1, 0, 0], 0],
  [[0, 0, 1, 0], 0],
  [[0, 0, 0, 1], 0],

  [[1, 0, 1, 0], 0],
  [[1, 0, 0, 1], 0],
  # [[0, 1, 0, 1], 0],
```

This is the array of learning templates each of them are array of data and correct result for that data.

As you see. last row commented - if I do uncomment it - perceptron will fail to learn. without it perceptron does not work right in case with "0101". So the **question is**:

1. Is this task can be solved with single neuron perceptron or should I use few layered perceptron?
2. How can I determine which tasks can be solved with such a simple perceptron? Are there any rule that I can apply to my task and say that it could be done with simple perceptron?

here is the **code of perceprton** written in [coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/):

```
class window.Perceptron
  weights: []
  calc: (signal) ->
    @neuron.calc signal
  adjust: ->
  foo: 0.1
  calc: (signal) ->
    sum = 0
    for s, i in signal
      sum += s*@weights[i]
    if sum>0.5 then return 1 else return 0
    sum
  learn: (templates) ->
    @weights = []
    for i in [1..templates[0][0].length]
      @weights.push Math.random()

    li = 0
    max_li = 50000
    console.log @weights
    while true
      gerror = 0
      li++
      for template, i in templates
        res = @calc template[0]
        # console.log "result: #{res}"
        error = template[1] - res
        gerror += Math.abs error
        for weight, i in @weights
          @weights[i] += @foo*error*template[0][i]
      if ((gerror == 0) || li > max_li) then break
    if gerror == 0
      console.log "Learned in #{li} iterations"
    else
      console.log "Learning failed after #{max_li} iterations"
    console.log @weights
```

Comment: What are your features?

Comment: not sure I understand you....

Comment: Is the perceptron directly assigning weights to each bit, or is something else going on?

Comment: Yes it is directly assign weights. Posted it's code.

Comment: as far as I can see, you have 16 possible inputs for a boolean function with a fairly complex "logic", and you expect your AI to find the right function if the answer for the input isn't specificied. it sounds a bit silly... (sry, it's just my intuition... perhaps because the state space is so small?)

Comment: Imagine the inputs to your perceptron as points in n-dimensional space. The perceptron algorithm attempts to find a hyperplane that divides the space into two sides, where one side contains all elements in one category and the other side contains all elements in the other category. Thus, it only works if the space can actually be divided in such a way. The inputs to your problem cannot be divided in such a way.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath - answer for the input IS specified. This is last element of learning_signals patterns.

Comment: @user2357112 it is not as simple to imagine how all that points would look in n-dimentional space but any way, this is quite good rule. Make it an answer and I'll accept it.